# Store images in picasso with a cache key of our own

Tags: android, android-image, picasso, image-caching

Is there a way I can load images into Picasso's image cache by specifying the cache key that is used ?

On a side note if that is not possible, I have made the necessary changes but I am not sure how to rebuild the jar. Any instructions to rebuild Picasso are much appreciated.

Comment: It seems a very logical question. I wonder why it has no answers!

Answer (score 5):

You can call stableKey on your requestCreator object.

https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#stableKey-java.lang.String-

It will be like:
`Picasso.with(context).load(yourURL).stableKey(yourKey).into(textView);`

Answer (score 0):

I not found no public access to this functionality, but for me works this workaround:

```
//1. Init picasso, create cache
mCache = new LruCache(mContext);
mPicasso = new Picasso.Builder(mContext).memoryCache(mCache).build();

//2. Load bitmap 
mPicasso.load(uri).resize(mThumbWidth, mThumbHeight).centerCrop().into(v, callback);

//3. In case of error (for example, in callback), you can manually download the picture and store to cache
Bitmap bmp = <custom load>
//make key
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(uri);
sb.append("\nresize:").append(mThumbWidth).append("x").append(mThumbHeight).append("\ncenterCrop\n");
mCache.set(sb.toString(), bmp);
```

Please note, that a key is used uri and your custom transformation (resize, centerCrop ant such, see more at com.squareup.picasso.Utils#createKey)

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me

```
String strUrl = WWW.sultan.com....;    
    Bitmap = bitmap;
    Picasso.with(Profile.this).load(strUrl).into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            userImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            this.bitmap = bitmap; //this can be used any where in the code   

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    });
```